# Highcharts mouse over point information

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need the information form mouse over on the point in Highcharts line chart, I tried to use tooltip but there is an error as: function statement requires a name. I have put the formatter in a plotOptions as the `onclick` function. I don't know if I can use these two options together. I need also to get the line names.

```js
   plotOptions:{
                series:{
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    point: {
                        events:{
                            click: function(e) {/*$("#displayText").html(e.currentTarget.y)*/ 
                             
                              tooltip: {
                          formatter: function () {
                             alert(this.x);
                                   }
                                   },
         }
                        }                        
                    },
     
                }
            },
```

Comment: Why is there a `tooltip.formatter` inside your `..point.events.click`?

Comment: @HalvorStrand when you click on a point it shows somw information like  x.axis of that point after click. I need these data after click on the point. Actually i want it to go to return this information after click on that selected point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was totally wrong. Here is the answer to retrieve line chart data.

```js
    plotOptions:{
                series:{
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    point: {
                        events:{
                            click: function() {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.series.name ); //this.x+1 is the msgID
                            }
                        }                        
                    },
     
                }
            },
```